# Core Data cross storage fetched property

Tags: cocoa, core-data, fetched-property

I'm currently wrapping my head around some problem with Core Data. 
I have one *user* model in its own store that I do not have any control over, as it gets shipped with a framework. A Persistent Store Coordinator, Managed Object Model and Context for this model gets created automatically and cannot be touched. In it, this model has a single *user* entity

On the other hand, I have a *properties* model with a *properties* entity in it that I have complete control over. In there I store properties for some *user* entities in the other store. Both user and property entities have an *id* attribute similar to a foreign key. 
This model has it's own Persistent Store Cordinator, Managed Object Model and Context.

What I now want is to have the associated *user* entity as an attribute of the *properties* entity so I might be able to bind to key-paths similar to `myproperty.user.someValueOfTheUserEntity` (I'm aware that myproperty might be an array when using fetched properties).

However, as cross-store relationships are not supported I thought of using a weak relationship via *Fetched Properties*. That one would just have to match the two corresponding *id* attributes. I have created a Fetched Property for the *user* in Xcode and the required accessors in my *properties* entity's class file (As suggested in other questions, I'm treating the values returned by the Fetched Property as an array).

However, I'm unable to set a destination entity for the Fetched Property in Xcode, as the target entity resides in a completely different store. Would I also have to define my *user* entity in the *properties* store? If so, how does Core Data know that that entity shall be fetched not from my properties store but from the users store?

Some threads mentioned using configurations for this, but I cannot find any documentation that goes further than mentioning "use configurations for this".

Can somebody enlighten me on how to set up cross-storage fetched properties? #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several persistent stores that share the same data model:

- Use single data model (xcdatamodeld) and add all your entities
- Create configurations (Editor/Add Configuration) for each "logical set" of
  entities that should be stored in separate store file
- Assign (Drag) entities to appropriate configurations
- Add configured persistent stores to your context (see below)
- Configure fetched properties

> ```
> // 1. Add "static", read-only store
> [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
>              configuration:@"your static configuration name goes here..."
>              URL:storeUrl
>              options:@{
>                  NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption: @(YES),
>                  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES)
>              }
>              error:&error];
> // 2. Add "dynamic", writable content
> [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
>              configuration:@"your dynamic configuration name goes here..."
>              URL:storeUrl
>              options:@{
>                 NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @(YES),
>                 NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES)
>              }
>              error:&error];
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response an help on this. 
However, now when now adding the read-only store an "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store" error is raised. 

The mom is created from the .xcdatamodel file that contains all entities in their configurations. Just adding the dynamic store does not raise the problem and also creates a .sqlite file with tables for all entities. Just adding the static store does not work. 

I've created a more detailed Gist (https://gist.github.com/3296730) with my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably that means that you have to recreate the store file (i.e. sqlite database) using the latest model.

My code: `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyModel" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];`

P.S. sorry for the very long delay with reply